# With svn deleting multiple files with the same prefix

Tags: svn

I have a svn folder with a bunch of image files in it. Something like this:

```
bigdog.png
bigcat.png
bigcow.png
smalldog.png
smallcat.png
smallcow.png
mediumsizecow.png
```

What would be the svn command to get rid of the `bigdog.png`, `bigcat.png` and `bigcow.png` all in one shot while leaving alone the other files? I would imagine it would be something like

`svn delete big*`

but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

When I try `svn delete big*` it only deletes one instance of the file and then tells me that  the particular file does not exist. No error message. So for example I would get:

```
D bigdog.png`
```

returns

> svn: 'bigdog.png' does not exist

Does this make any sense?

**Update 2:**

I've also tried `svn delete big*.png` and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Why does svn delete big* not work ? Error Messages ? Windows ? Yes than you have to use svn delete big*.png ...

Comment: Are those files in your working directory? Are they under version control?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on UNIX, you can try following command:

```
find . -type f -not \( -name *.svn-base -prune \) -name "big*" | xargs svn delete --force
```

Under windows it will look as follows:

```
for /r %i in (big*) do svn delete --force %i
```

Comment: I tried the UNIX version and got `svn: '.svn/props' is not a working copy`.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using newer Windows Systems, you can do it in PowerShell using:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse big*.png | ForEach-Object {svn del $_}
```

This assumes you have PowerShell and an SVN client installed on the same machine.